# Nginx configuration question

Tags: debian, nginx

Hey guys, i'm trying to make the autoindex feature only run for my ip address with this code:

server{
...
autoindex off;
...
if ($remote_addr ~ **.**.**.**) {
    autoindex on;
}
...
}
But it doesn't work. It gives my a 403 :/ Can someone help me :)
Btw, i'm using Debian Lenny and Nginx 0.6 :)

EDIT: Here's my full configuration:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  site.com;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    client_max_body_size 4M;
    server_tokens off;
#   log_subrequest on;  
    autoindex off;
#   expires max;
    error_page   500 502 503 504 /var/www/nginx-default/50x.html;

#   error_page  404  /404.html;

    set $myhome /bla/bla;
    set $myroot $myhome/public;
    set $mysubd $myhome/subdomains;

    log_format  new_log
    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
            '"$status" "$http_referer" '
            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # Star nginx :@
    access_log /bla/bla/logs/access.log new_log;
    error_log /bla/bla/logs/error.log;

    if ($remote_addr ~ 94.156.58.138) {
        autoindex on;
    }

    # Subdomains
    if ($host ~* (.*)\.site\.org$) {
        set $myroot $mysubd/$1;
    }


    # Static files
#   location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
#       access_log        off;
#       expires           30d;
#   }

    location / {
        root  $myroot;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    # PHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $myroot$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # .Htaccess
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

}
```

I forgot to mention that when i add the code to remove static files from my access log, the static files cannot be accessed. I don't know if it's relevant :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this in a fairly hacky way by using a version of the technique [described here by Endre Szabó](http://end.re/2011/05/02/nginx-alternative-root-with-conditional-autoindex/).

Essentially it's to enable autoindex unconditionally (I don't believe there is currently any *other* way to enable it) and then to forbid access to directories where there is no index.html present, unless the requesting IP address matches the specific one defined in the configuration.

```
server {
    autoindex on;

    location / {
        root   /your/htdocs;

        # If the requested filename is not a directory,
        # stop processing further conditions.
        if (!-d $request_filename) {
            break;
        }

        # If index.html exists in the requested directory,
        # stop processing any further conditions.
        if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
            break;
        }

        # If the requesting IP address is not our special one,
        # forbid the request, inhibiting autoindex.
        if ($remote_addr != "1.2.3.4") {
            return 403;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
if ($remote_addr = "94.156.58.138") {
    autoindex on;
fi
```

Comment: I did an edit of my original post :)

Comment: When i test the configuration, it says that i can't use autoindex in there :/ Is this feature available in the 0.8 version ? If it's available, i'll switch to it immediatelly!